# Word for an all seeing society/government type

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, neologisms, word-formation

I'm looking for a word to mean a society or government type where everything is visible or known to everyone, similar to *omniscient*. For example, if everyone (including government) can see everything everyone does because of surveillance, but most things are legal so it's not necessarily a negative connotation. I thought [reading this list of words](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:List_of_forms_of_government) might trigger my memory, but it didn't.

Something like "optocracy", though I just made that word up. I could swear I once heard the correct word for it used in an interview I had seen, but haven't been able to find the video or even the word.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_transparency

Comment: The term *Ombudsman* comes to mind but he is not necessarily an official.

Comment: Following up on the comment by @Ridici, I believe "radical transparency"  taken to the limit accurately describes the form of society you're seeking. Check out the 2017 movie *The Circle*. That said, neither of these leads provides a single word for this form of completely open, totally transparent society.

Comment: I wonder if "panopticon" can be modified to fit this meaning. Panopticon is defined as:
`A building, as a prison, hospital, library, or the like, so arranged that all parts of the interior are visible from a single point`.

Comment: It's worth noting that just because something is known by everyone doesn't necessarily make it common knowledge. (Look up the 'blue eyes' paradox.)